# If a Fourier series converges uniformly to a limit function, is the limit always the same as the original function?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

Let $ f: \mathbb{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ .
$f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ is the set of continuous $\mathbb{C}$ valued functions on $\mathbb{T}$ = unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$

Let $ S_N(f) := \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta} $ be the partial sum of the Fourier series of $ f $, where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the "$n$th Fourier coefficient of $f$"

Is the following true or false:

If $S_N(f)$ converges uniformly to a function $g$, then $g = f$

If it is true, is there a well-known theorem that proves this statement?
If it is false, can it be made true by adding extra conditions on $f$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: did you intend to write "Let $f:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$"? Or "$f\in C(\mathbb{T})$"?

Comment: Oh yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true.

Indeed, if $(S_N(f))$ converges uniformly to $g$, then its Cesaro means converge also to $g$. But by [Fejér's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem), these means converge to $f$, so by uniqueness of the limit, one has $f=g$.